# Adding An Image To A Custom Taxonomy Term

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I would like to be able to associate an image with a custom taxonomy term. Ideally, I'd like to provide the end-user with an interface for managing the image directly on the term itself.

I have worked with a plugin that provides this functionality (Ultimate Taxonomy Manager) - it may be what I stick with. I'm after the best practice, though, and would like to know if any of you have worked through this before and what solutions you recommend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [`How TO custom taxonomies extra fields`](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-taxonomies-extra-fields) is whats you are looking for?

Comment: I think this is it! I'll give it a try - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to add a custom field (an image field) to you custom taxonomy group or individual taxonomies.